# How can I ensure that only one KeyBinding command is executed when a keyboard shortcut is used?

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings

I have the following KeyBindings:

```
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+S" Command="Save" />
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+Shift+S" Command="SaveAs" />
```

When I press Ctrl+Shift+S to execute the `SaveAs` command, it works -- but directly afterwards, the `Save` command is also executed. Is this caused by my Gesture definitions?

Comment: have you marked the RoutedEvent as Handled=true using the RoutedEventArgs parameter in you method that handles the save?

Comment: That was it! Why can't I just hire you to sit on my shoulder and remind me of things like that?

Comment: @JfBeaulac I think it is a good idea to post your comment as an answer, then Showtime can accept it for points and also so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mark the RoutedEvent as `Handled=true` using the `RoutedEventArgs` parameter in your method that handles the save.